# CVOpenGLESTextureRef to Photo Library

Tags: ios, opengl-es

**Background**

I am using the AVCaptureStillImageOutput to capture and perform processing on a still image with the assistance of OpenGL.

I am using the CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef and a CVOpenGLESTextureRef to store the texture. The texture is being represented in OpenGL in the format GL_RGBA.

**Question**

After performing the processing on the image, I would like to save the texture to the user's photo library.

I was wondering if anybody has done this before and what the simplest and cheapest way of going about this would be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks:)